# testing all matched routes (*path) in rails in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes, rails-routing

I have a rails application and I am trying to test the routes file.

How can one test this route in the routes.rb in rspec(minitest would be great as well):

`'*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#raise_not_found!', :via => :all`

Comment: What testing framework do you use? Minitest, RSpec?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Routing specs in RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs) you should be able to write something like this:

```
# in spec/routing/not_found.rb
describe 'not found' do
  it 'routes to application#raise_not_found' do
    expect(:get => "/an-unknown-route").to route_to(
      :controller => "application",
      :action     => "raise_not_found!"
    )
  end
end
```